# How to expand ipv6 address using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipv6

I want to convert shorthand notation of ipv6 address to longhand notation of ipv6 addressing format; I know we can perform various operations on ip addresses using `ipaddress` library. For example I want to convert `::abc:7:def` to `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0abc:0007:0def`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for the `exploded` property of the `IPv6Address` object. You get this through calling `ipaddress.ip_address`:

```
> import ipaddress
> addr = ipaddress.ip_address('::abc:7:def')
> print(addr.exploded)
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0abc:0007:0def
```

Comment: Make sure to enter the IPv6 address as unicode or you may run into errors on Python 2

Comment: This also works for "IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses": `import ipaddress; print(ipaddress.ip_address('::ffff:192.0.2.128').exploded)` -> `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:c000:0280`. Which is nice. :)